# How can I attach a fileDownloader to a button renderer in Vaadin 7 framework

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using a grid in vaadin 7. Each row contains data about an object. One cell contains a file name. I want to put a download button in each row that causes the associated file to be downloaded.

Grids are supposed to be used with ButtonRenderers, rather than buttons. I have used vaadin.server.FileDownloader before, but always with an actual button rather than a renderer. When using a button you connect the button to the downloader using

```
downloader.extend(button);
```

But I can't see how to do it using a ButtonRenderer.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missunderstanding the purpose of ButtonRenderers.

You actually add `Button` to `Grid` and then, put a ButtonRenderer in that column, so you can use the button as usually.